# Android keyboard keeps appearing after closed

Tags: javascript, android, android-browser

I have a textarea in my html. When the user taps on it, the keyboard properly pops up. After hitting the keyboard close button, the keyboard keeps appearing when tapping elsewhere on the screen. Is there a way to have keyboard only appear on input taps?

Answer (score 0):

The following bit of jquery code does the trick:

```
$(window).bind('touchstart', function (e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is(':input')) {
        $(':input').blur();
    }   
});
```

Basically, I catch every tap; if the target is not an input field, blur all the input fields, which in effect hides the silly keyboard.